# SSRS 2019 Customize CSS

Tags: reporting-services

We're upgrading from ssrs 2012 to 2019. In 2012 there used to be physical files for this, but that doesn't seem to be the case in 2019. Does anyone know if there is a way to customize the css that the new 2019 web tool uses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no longer any way to do this in the Portal (used to be called ReportManager).

The best you can do is the "Branding" functionality that was added, but it's only available in "Enterprise Edition", and it's extremely limited. That feature essentially allows you to upload a .json file (and some others) that defines colors in a certain way. At runtime, that file is manually "merged" into an embedded resource file named "UniversalBrand.less" that's inside one of the Portal's .dll files. The result of that merge/transform is then served to the client as "/assets/css/brand.css".